# Graphics, PlotRange and/or PlotRegion

Tags: graphics, options

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
  Module[{pts},
   pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {6, 0}};
   Graphics[{Blue, Polygon[pts]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]
  ]
```

A graphic is displayed that doesn't entirely fall within the plotrange.

Question : I have a Panel that displays graphics of different shapes and size. When automatic resizing of the graphic is not an option what is the best way to calculate the plotrange ( or any other suitable option ) so that graphics fit ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem completely. Would `PlotRange -> {{Min[pts[[All, 1]]], Max[pts[[All, 1]]]}, {Min[pts[[All, 2]]], Max[pts[[All, 2]]]}}` help (perhaps together with `ImageSize`)?

Comment: I must admit I don't really understand from your question what you want to achieve. Would `PlotRange->All` solve your problem?

Comment: It's that any g can come in ( calculated from numerical data, or manually drawn or changed by time ). Graphics may move out of 'PlotRange' that's the issue.  But I think Zachars answer helped me.

Comment: You say you have a `Panel`. Can you provide the code for that `Panel` so it becomes clearer what you want to do with the graphics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

First the plot is generated with the defaults of `PlotRange -> All` and then the explicit `PlotRange` value is extracted (possibly modified) and the plot is displayed at the end:

```
Module[{pts, g, opt}, pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {6, 0}};
 g = Graphics[{Blue, Polygon[pts]}, PlotRange -> All];
 opt = First@AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange];
 Show[g, opt]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think that First@AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange] does, yes. I mean any g, can come in.